# Remove Trailing Slash From the URL

Tags: asp.net, webforms, web-config

I want to redirect "abc.aspx/" to "abc.aspx". How can this be done?

Page gets broken when requested page ends with '/'. How to handle such type of requests?
Is there any rewriting rule that can be added into web.config file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your web.config, under the `system.webServer`, add

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>

    <!--To always remove trailing slash from the URL-->
    <rule name="Remove trailing slash" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)/$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>

  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Some Gotchas

In your development environment, if you run your web site under Visual Studio Development Sever, you won't be able to see this feature working. You will need to configure your application to run under at least IIS Express.

When you deploy your web site and see that this feature is not working on your production server, it will be because you miss configured something. One of the common mistakes is having `overrideModeDefault` attribute set to `Deny` for rules under `<sectionGroup name="rewrite">` inside your *applicationHost.config* file.

If you are on a shared hosting environment and you see that this feature is not working, ask your provider if they have given you the permission of configuring this part.

Source: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/remove-trailing-slash-from-the-urls-of-your-asp-net-web-site-with-iis-7-url-rewrite-module

Comment: Thanks, seems to be working. Followed all the steps mentioned. But still UI of the page looks broken. Dont what exactly wrong in there.

Comment: If you need further help with some other issues it would be best to open a new question in which you describe as best as you can your problem.

Comment: thanks, I have changed my routing table to handling old urls of my site. Your solution fix my error without change any thing in RouteConfig.cs

Comment: Microsoft Edge forces the slash at the end.

Comment: I added this rule to my web.config file but it does not remove the trailing slash at all. Still get a 404 when the url is like https://example.com/page.asp/

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but Mihai's answer can make your application vulnerable to open redirects attack (see [this](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet.html))

```
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="{R:1}" />
```

This redirect URL can be used for an external redirect, so make sure you have other validations in place before this rule is evaluated or change the redirect to make it internal instead. If you really want to remove the trailing slash and keep it internal, you can change it to:

```
<action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
```

Cheers